# Use Django Migrations to delete a table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am moving from Rails to Django and have an existing database. I created `models.py` via `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`, made changes, and tested some endpoints. Everything seems fine.

I then ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate` to make the initial django mirgation.

I noticed an old Rail's specific Model / table called `ArInternalMetadata` / `ar_internal_metadata`. I figure I could easily remove the table by simply removing the model from `models.py` and rerun `makemigrations` however when I do that, django just says `No changes detected`. Running `migrate` doesn't remove the table either.

Comment: If there is no `migrations` subfolder in your app's folder, you need to migrate that app explicitly via `makemigrations <app_name>`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066671/how-to-delete-models-from-django

Comment: `managed = False` in the `Meta` inner class was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. When `inspectdb` creates Models from an existing database, it sets `managed` in the `Meta` inner class to `False` by default.

```py
class AssetCategories(FacadeModel):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'asset_categories'
```

Per the [Django 2.1 Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#managed) this will prevent deletion from happening

> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model

Removing `managed = False` from the `Meta` class allows `makemigrations` / `migrate` to delete the table.